# How to compare growth rates

Tags: time-series, data-mining, normalization

I'm analyzing the growth rate of a data set, and am unsure what is the best approach to make sure the growth is independent from another data set.

Taking a simple (fictive) example, I'd like to evaluate the growth rate of internet searches for "Pepsi", independently from the underlying growth rate of all internet searches.

What would be the best way to visualize that the "Pepsi" searches are growing from 2000 to 2007 at the same rate as overall searches, and only become more popular starting in 2008?

Should I calculate the annual growth rate for each set, and analyze the ratio between both values for each year? Or is there another way?
Thanks for any input!

[image: Growth rate example]